Creating an Entra ID group that allows PIM Microsoft Entra roles
I have got the snippet of code below. The objective is to create a group that allows Microsoft Entra roles to be assigned to the group. The snippet below creates the group, however it doesnt work with entra ID role assignment for PIM.
New-MgGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname  -MailNickName $groupfullname -MailEnabled:$false -SecurityEnabled -IsAssignableToRole:$true

I find that if I create the group using the PowerShell code below, the group gets created, I find that any user that gets added to the group after assigning an Entra/Azure resource role to the group gets such roles permanently rather than via the privilege identity management solution.
If I create the group manually, it works as expected i.e via PIM role assignment etc.


Could you include and confirm how you are assigning PIM Entra role to group?

New-MgGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname  -MailNickName $groupfullname -MailEnabled -SecurityEnabled -IsAssignableToRole ,note the difference between boolean parameters and switch parameters.

The group is being assigned using the cmdlet New-AzRoleAssignment what seems to be happening is that the role is permanently assigned.

For PIM role assignments, you should not use the standard role assignment cmdlet (New-AzRoleAssignment) that assigns Azure role permanently.
In your case, creation of role-assignable group via PowerShell is correct but the issue is with usage of wrong command to assign PIM role.
Initially, I created one group by running same PowerShell command like this:
$groupfullname = "testpimgroup"
New-MgGroup -DisplayName $groupfullname  -MailNickName $groupfullname -MailEnabled:$false -SecurityEnabled -IsAssignableToRole:$true

Response:

Portal:

To assign Azure resource role like "Contributor" PIM eligible role assignment to group, you can make use of below sample PowerShell script:
$guid = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()  
$startTime = Get-Date -Format o 
$scope = "/subscriptions/subId/"
New-AzRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest -Name $guid -Scope $scope -ExpirationDuration PT1H -ExpirationType AfterDuration -PrincipalId "groupId" -RequestType AdminAssign -RoleDefinitionId subscriptions/subId/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/roledefId -ScheduleInfoStartDateTime $startTime

Response:

Portal:

Similarly, make use of below sample PowerShell script to assign eligible PIM Microsoft Entra role like Application Admin to group:
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Identity.Governance

$startTime = Get-Date -Format o

$params = @{
    action = "adminAssign"
    justification = "Assign Application Admin eligibility to group"
    roleDefinitionId = "9b895d92-2cd3-44c7-9d02-a6ac2d5ea5c3"
    directoryScopeId = "/"
    principalId = "groupId"
    scheduleInfo = @{
        startDateTime = $startTime
        expiration = @{
            type = "afterDateTime"
            endDateTime = [System.DateTime]::Parse("2024-11-10T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }
}

New-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleEligibilityScheduleRequest -BodyParameter $params

Response:

Portal:

